# SQLAlchemy Select statement - SQL Syntax Error

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have created a table (MySQL 5.1)

```
from sqlalchemy import *

def get():
    db = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/database')
    db.echo = True
    metadata = MetaData(db)

    feeds = Table('feeds', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('title', String(100)),
            Column('link', String(255)),
            Column('description', String(255)),
    )

    entries = Table('entries', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('fid', Integer),
            Column('url', String(255)),
            Column('title', String(255)),
            Column('content', String(5000)),
            Column('date', DateTime),
    )
    feeds.create()
    entries.create()
```

But when I try to query it:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
db = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/database')
metadata = MetaData(db)
feeds = Table('feeds', metadata)
s = feeds.select()
result = db.execute(s)
```

I get an error on the result = db.execute(s) line indicating the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM feeds' at line 2") 'SELECT  \nFROM feeds' ()
```

I'm obviously new to SQLAlchemy, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, despite having googled every tutorial on the web and changed this a million times.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect [`Table.select()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/schema.html?highlight=select#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select) is only for selecting specific columns. For `SELECT *`, the [expression language tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/sqlexpression.html#selecting) uses this syntax instead:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
s = select([feeds])
result = db.execute(s)
```

Comment: Any progress? We can't really help you more if you don't respond to our first suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

there's something missing probably from your feeds.select() call, I'd have another look at the API documentation for this function.